# ActionBarSherlock setCustomView not working in Android 3.2

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, actionbarsherlock

I recently upgraded my application to use ActionBarSherlock 4.1. Since the upgrade users running the app on Honeycomb experiance a force close due to a null pointer exception when setting a custom view on the actionbar.

I add a custom view containing two spinners to the actionbar this works on Android 4.0 & 4.1 but is not working on 3.2.

```
            bar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar);// spinners
            actionBarViewHolder= new CustomActionBarViewHolder();
            actionBarViewHolder.categorySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.actionbar_catergory);
            actionBarViewHolder.sortBySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.actionbar_sortby);
```

On Android 3.2 the spinners can not be found yet on 4.0 and 4.1 they views are found and anything runs smoothly.

I have not tried the application on a 3.0 emulator but I image the problem persists.

Any ideas what could be the problem?

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.5">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Category:" />

    <Spinner android:id="@+id/actionbar_catergory"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/actionbar_spinner_catergory"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_background" />
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.5">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Sort By:" />

    <Spinner android:id="@+id/actionbar_sortby"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/actionbar_spinner_sortby" android:background="@drawable/spinner_background" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this, its working fine on all devices or you can check the demo code [here](http://www.androiddevelopersolution.com/2013/07/actionbarsherlock-with-custom-view.html)

```
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_top); // load your layout
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

Images

[image]

Comment: there is nothing in the link now

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar, null);
bar.setCustomView(view);// spinners
actionBarViewHolder= new CustomActionBarViewHolder();
actionBarViewHolder.categorySpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_catergory);
actionBarViewHolder.sortBySpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_sortby);
```

Comment: Sadly. This did not work. The spinners are still null on Honeycomb when using the inflater.

Comment: The view was created and exists so Spinners aren't children of this view. Potential reasons: 1. wrong ids, 2. spinners aren't children of the view 3. findViewById invoked on wrong view

Comment: custom_action_bar contains two children linear layouts which contain the spinners. I have added the xml layout.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code how I create custom action bar with actiobBarSherlock

```
 private void createCustomActionBar() {

    List<SiteLink> links = new ArrayList<SiteLink>();
    links.add(...)  
    LinksAdapter linkAdapter = new LinksAdapter(this, R.layout.external_link, links);

    View customNav = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_show_action_bar, null);
    IcsSpinner spinner = (IcsSpinner)customNav.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(linkAdapter);


    ImageView refresh = (ImageView) customNav.findViewById(R.id.refresh);
    refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ...
        }
    });

    ImageView settings = (ImageView) customNav.findViewById(R.id.settings);
    settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ...
        }
    });

    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customNav, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(Gravity.RIGHT));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

}
```

Adapter

```
private static class LinksAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SiteLink> {

    private List<SiteLink> strings;
    private Context context;

    private LinksAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<SiteLink> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.strings = objects;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (strings == null) return 0;
        return strings.size();
    }

    @Override
    public SiteLink getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
    }


    // return views of drop down items
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final SiteLink siteLink = strings.get(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // at 0 position show only icon

        TextView site = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.external_link, null);
        site.setText(siteLink.getName());

        site.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(siteLink.getUrl()));
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        return site;


    }


    // return header view of drop down
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.icon, null);
    }
}
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:gravity="right"
        >


    <com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

     <ImageView  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:src="@drawable/ic_navigation_refresh"
                 android:paddingRight="20dp"
                 android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                 android:layout_gravity="center"
                 android:background="@drawable/action_buttons_background"
                 android:id="@+id/refresh"/>


    <ImageView  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/action_buttons_background"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/settings"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No joy using     View customNav = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_show_action_bar, null);

Comment: you can use non static LayoutInflater initialization. for example LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); inflanter.inflate...

Comment: That also doesn't work. It seems that Honeycomb can not find the layout to inflate?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put your two children `LinearLayout`'s inside a main `LinearLayout`?. Also try to not repeat the id from the children `LinearLayout`'s, because you're making your id's system cry. But I'm almost sure your problem is that you have more than one main Layouts in the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for setCustomView using actionbarsherlib. 
It is worked in android 3.2 version also.

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);
    Button mybutton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button1);            
    mybutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
            /** Your click actions here. */
            }
    });
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code.here I added Sherlock bar library to my project.then, I used here for set my Title on header(Top). like this..
just try this like.. Set target SDK to Android 3.2(Version 14) or above..

```
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.header_sherlock_xmllayout);
    header_tvleft = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header_tvleft);
    header_tvleft.setText("Back");
```

try this method....